# How to use Phoenix.Token when registering a user

Tags: phoenix-framework

I know that the phoenix token can be generated as follows

```
 Phoenix.Token.sign(MyApp.Endpoint, "user", user_id)
```

and based on the documentation, is suggested to use the user's id for the generation. The problem is that I'm trying to generate this token in the changeset, at the moment of user creation, thus I don't have any user's id yet, what would be the best way to use Phoenix.Token.sign? At the moment I'm using 
`put_change(:api_token, :base64.encode(:crypto.strong_rand_bytes(24)))`
but I would like to use Phoenix.Token if possible.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Phoenix.Token.sign in a meta tag, passing the connection, user salt, and user.id. Once signed, verify the token upon connecting to the socket. Remember, you must pass the same user salt when verifying as when the token was signed. For example, here is the meta tag in my application, which uses a "players" resource as opposed to "users"

*app.html.eex*

```
<%= tag :meta, name: "channel_token", content: Phoenix.Token.sign(@conn, "player auth", :player_id) %>
```

Note: I have the current players id stored in the session as player_id. I'm using "player auth" as the salt and the name of my token is "channel_token".

*socket.js*

```
var token = $("meta[name=channel_token]").attr("content");
var socket = new Socket("/socket", {
    params: {
        token: token
    }
});
```

Grab the token named "channel token" and pass it into the socket params. Once the token is signed and passed into the socket you can verify it in the "connect" function in *user_socket*.